# ASP.Net MVC async with LINQ Lambda select results in "A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, async-await

I have been battling with what is proving to be a diffuclt to track down issue involving awaited tasks within a LINQ Lambda select.

**Note:** The code below has been simplified and uses demo naming i.e. Town, Region etc. But the workflow is the same as the original code in which the issue occurs.

- Code runs perfectly when stepping in VS debugger.
- But when running in non-debug mode if a town is > level 1 and the `await this.CheckTownSpecialProperty(t)` function is called, I end up getting `A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed.`.
- This error is only thrown when running in non-debug mode. In debug mode it works fine, presumably because stepping prevents the concurrency clash on the context.
- I have read the Microsoft warnings about the dangers of async within LINQ Lambda selects caused by the deferred execution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async
- I basically just want to know why it happens in this case even with the usage of the using blocks controlling the contexts.

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<TownSearchOutputDto>> GetTowns(TownSearchInputDto input)
        {
            var numResults = 25;

            var query = _townRepository.GetAll()
                                          .Include(t => t.Tests)
                                          .Include(t => t.Region.Select(s => s.SubRegion))
                                          .Include(t => t.Province); // Eager load relations.

            // Filter based on CountyId.
            if (input.CountyId > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(t => t.CountyId == input.CountyId);
            }

            var townList = await query
                                    .OrderBy(t => t.Name)
                                    .Take(numResults)
                                    .ToListAsync();

            IEnumerable<Task<TownSearchOutputDto>> tasks = townList.Select(async t => {
                var townLevel = this.GetTownLevel(t);
                bool hasSomeSpecialTownProperty = false;
                if (townLevel.Key > 1)
                {
                    hasSomeSpecialTownProperty = await this.CheckTownSpecialProperty(t);
                }
                return new TownSearchOutputDto
                {
                    Id = t.Id,
                    CountyId = t.CountyId,
                    RegionName = t.Region.Name,
                    SubRegionName = t.SubRegion.Name,
                    ProvinceName = t.Province.Name,
                    TownLevelOrder = townLevel.Key,
                    TownLevelName = townLevel.Value,
                    HasSomeSpecialTownProperty = hasSomeSpecialTownProperty,
                    Disabled = townLevel.Key > 2 || t.Tests.Any(a => a.TownId == t.Id)
                };
            }).ToList();

            var towns = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            return towns;
        }

        private KeyValuePair<int, string> GetTownLevel(Town town)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(town.Tiny))
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "Tiny");
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(town.Small))
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Small");
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(town.Big))
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Big");
            }
            return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(-1, null);
        }

        private async Task<bool> CheckTownSpecialProperty(Town town)
        {
            // If no town is found then we cannot continue.
            if (town is null)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException("Town not found. Cannot continue!");
            }

            var townLevel = this.GetTownLevel(town);

            if(townLevel.Key == 1) // This is big town level, exit early. We are just testing against smaller towns.
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Find any big town of the same name also being tested.
            // This is where the issue occurs.
            // In debug mode all works well but when running freely, I get: 
            // "A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed."
            var townList = await _townRepository.GetAll()
                                            .Include(t => t.Tests)
                                            .Include(t => t.Region.Select(s => s.SubRegion))
                                            .Include(t => t.Province); // Eager load relations.
                .Where(t => t.Id != town.Id
                                && t.Region.Name == town.Region.Name
                                && t.Name == town.Name
                                && t.SubRegion.Name == town.SubRegion.Name
                                && t.Tests.Any(a => a.TownId == t.Id))
                .ToListAsync();

            // If we have found a big town also being tested return true.
            if (townList.Any(t => this.GetTownLevel(t).Key == 1))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

### Things I have tried to resolve the issue

1. Making `CheckTownSpecialProperty()` synchronous. But this defeats the purpose of GetTowns being asynchronous to begin with, it was really just to let me know the funtion was working OK.
2. I tried to add using blocks and control the context instances manually. I surmised that this would work since the context instances would be recreated for each task.

   - But this results in: `"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."`
   - I also tried the same in the GetTowns() function and the same `"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."` error is thrown.

```
        List<Town> townList = null;
        using (var context = _abpContext.GetDbContext())
            {     
                townList = await context.Towns
                                .Include(t => t.Tests)
                                .Include(t => t.Region.Select(s => s.SubRegion))
                                .Include(t => t.Province); // Eager load relations.
                .Where(t => t.Id != town.Id
                                && t.Region.Name == town.Region.Name
                                && t.Name == town.Name
                                && t.SubRegion.Name == town.SubRegion.Name
                                && t.Tests.Any(a => a.TownId == t.Id))
                .ToListAsync();
            }
```

3. Turning off Lazy Loading on the contexts in the using block via `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`. I was hoping that fully materialising the objects would prevent the error, but this made no difference.
4. Adding `AsNoTracking()` to the queries. This was a last try to see if I could fully materialise the objects and prevent the concurrency issues. Sadly it did not work.

Comment: Can't for the life of me see why this question was downvoted. This was a tricky issue to debug and I have included all pertinant information and also all the steps I took to resolve. I also included the debug error which I received. Do not understand the downvote at all.

Comment: @jiraya don't worry about the downvotes, you are on StackOverflow in 2021. The good times will not be back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in `GetTowns`. Here's what that code is doing:

1. Creates a `query`.
2. Asynchronously executes that query against `_townRepository` to get `townList`.
3. Spins up several tasks, where several of them may be calling `CheckTownSpecialProperty`.
4. Asynchronously waits for all those tasks to complete using `Task.WhenAll`.

So `CheckTownSpecialProperty` may be called concurrently, and all those concurrent executions use the same `_townRepository`. This is not allowed.

To fix this, either:

1. Make your original `query` more complex (e.g., doing a join) so that a second lookup isn't necessary.
2. New up a repository within `CheckTownSpecialProperty`, so that each of the concurrent executions have their own repository.
3. Change the logic so that the secondary queries in `CheckTownSpecialProperty` are run one at a time. They can still be asynchronous, but serial.
4. Combine the secondary queries into a single secondary query.

Comment: Thanks a million for the response Stephen, much appreciated. Reagrding the suggestions, one or two questions. Would my attempt at newing up a context via a using block not have achieved solution 2? That was my assumption also but I kept getting a context already disposed error on it. If you have the time, what would solution 3. look like, thanks again, much appreciated?

Comment: Yes, if `_abpContext.GetDbContext` returns a *new* DbContext, then it should work as solution (2). Solution (3) would look like `var towns = new List<TownSearchOutputDto>(); foreach (var t in townList) { var townLevel = this.GetTownLevel(t); ... towns.Add(new TownSearchOutputDto { ... }); }`

Comment: Thanks a million Stephen, this really helped me out. You are a gentleman.

Comment: Also for anyone else with this issue see Stephen's "new" point in the comment above. This is why my using block did not work, GetDbContext() did not create a new context as I had imagined, it merely returns the active one to me. Hence the using block killed it on first execution thereby crashing on the next call to the context.